# Gatsby Transformer Remark slow when watching large numbers of files

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I am currently working on a documentation website for a CSS design system - think Material Design - using Gatsby. In order to not duplicate content from each of our components’ README markdown files I have used the Transformer Remark plugin to read these markdown files, render them as HTML and display at various URLs using a custom template.

The above process is now complete but I have started to notice as the number of components added to the site increases so too does the load on Transformer Remark’s watch task. Our design system now has around 30-40 components and as each component’s package can contain multiple markdown files this means TR is watching around 80 files. My laptop fan is going crazy.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could reduce the load and also does Gatsby have to run its onCreatePages function constantly?